# On permuted sum of squares of primes in a list

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, permutations, sums-of-squares

We want to pick a set of distinct primes (if not possible, then just positive numbers) $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_k$ such that there exists $t$ permutations, $\sigma_1(\cdot)$,$\sigma_2(\cdot),\dots,\sigma_t(\cdot)$, of the primes  such that the sum of vectors $$(p_1^2,p_2^2,\dots,p_k^2)+(p_{\sigma_1(1)}^2,p_{\sigma_1(2)}^2,\dots,p_{\sigma_1(k)}^2)+\dots+(p_{\sigma_t(1)}^2,p_{\sigma_t(2)}^2,\dots,p_{\sigma_t(k)}^2)=(T,T,T,....,T)$$ where $T=O(k^c)$ for some constant $c > 0$.

Is this possible and how do you do this? Given a $k$, can $t$ be as small as $O(\log(k))$?

For every $k$ is there a polynomially big $T$ and a $t$ that is logarithmic in $k$?

From Gerry's comments: let us fix $t=2$, for every $k$, is there a $T$ that is polynomial in $k$ that satisfies the above relations? His comments provide existence of values of $k$ such that $T=k$ but does not cover all $k$.

Comment: If you don't insist on primes, $t$ can be taken to be 2, regardless of $k$; all you need is a number $T$ that has $k/2$ representations as a sum of two squares (OK, $k$ has to be even). I suspect there are numbers that can be written as the sum of two squares of primes in arbitrarily many ways, but I don't know that for a fact.

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A088919 for Smallest number having exactly $n$ representations as sum of two squares of distinct primes.

Comment: But the sum of squares have to be permutations of one another? How does 2 work? say p1^+p2^2=T, there should be some other p_3 in the list such that p_^2+p_3^2=T. right?

Comment: oh no. I see what you are saying... hmm let me think

Comment: oic for t>=3, the problem seems hard. right?

Comment: For $t=3$ (and $k$ divisible by 3), all you need is numbers with a lot of representations as sums of three squares (of distinct primes). And so on.

Comment: Got it. Can I guarantee the condition $T = O(k^c)$ as well?

Comment: but if I insist on primes is it hard? If they are not primes, I have to force extra condition on the pairs of gcds for my application.

Comment: I don't know the answer to the primes questions, since I don't know what's known about numbers that are the sum of squares of $k$ distinct primes in many ways --- but I bet the analytic number theorists have answers.

Comment: "exactly n representations as sum of two squares of distinct primes" is there a reference for this type of problem?

Comment: So the topic is analytic number theory? any references?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that familiar with the literature. "Hardy-Littlewood circle method" and "sieve methods" may be applicable.

Comment: Consider sums of three squares of primes that are all between $X$ and $2X$.  Counted with multiplicity there are $\gg X^3/(\log X)^3$ such sums.  They all lie below $12X^2$.  Therefore some integer must be represented very many times.

Comment: @Lucia Could you elaborate your answer in the answer section? Gerry's idea of two squares is very interesting as well. If you could provide some insights, it will be great. Thankyou.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you want.  Gerry Myerson's answer exhibits such permutations when $k$ is a multiple of $t$ and given an integer that is a sum of $t$ squares of primes in many ways.  My pigeonhole argument shows that for $t\ge 3$ there are numbers with many representations as a sum of $t$ squares of primes.  By working a little bit harder one could also find numbers with many representations as sums of two squares of primes.  But your problem is not very clear to me: what specific relation between $k$, $t$, and $T$ are you looking for?

Comment: I would like to have T polynomially growing with k and t as small as possible.

Comment: I think Gerry's answer fixes t=2 which is as small as possible. The question then is: is T is polynomially growing as k? For every k is there a polynomially big T such that t is logarithmic in k. This is what the question boils down to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For large $k$ it is always possible to do this with $30$ permutations.  Write $k$ as $30a+6b+5c$ where $0\le b\le 4$ and $0\le c\le 5$. Then the permutations will be a product of $a$ disjoint $30$-cycles, $b$ disjoint $6$-cycles, and $c$ disjoint $5$ cycles (take a cycle consisting of the first thirty primes, then the next thirty primes etc until we get to the last five primes).  The resulting permutation has order thirty and its powers are the thirty permutations we want.  (The basic idea here is what was expressed in Gerry Myerson's comments to the question.  Myerson's observation is that when $k$ is a multiple of $3$, one can use products of three cycles, and three permutations suffice.  In general this would allow one to take the smallest prime dividing $k$ as a possible answer.  What is covered here is all the cases when $k$ does not have a small prime factor.)

For the sums to add up to the same number, we must find a number $N$ such that $30N$ is expressible as the sum of thirty squares of distinct primes in at least $a$ ways; $6N$ is expressible as the sum of six squares of distinct primes in at least $b$ ways; and $5N$ is expressible as the sum of five squares of distinct primes in at least $5$ ways. This can be arranged thanks to the Hardy-Littlewood circle method.

It may not be easy to find an exact reference that does so however.  So here's a little context.  It is an old conjecture that every integer that is $4 \pmod {24}$ is the sum of four squares of primes.  This remains difficult to prove.  However Hua showed in 1938 that every large integer that is $5 \pmod{24}$ may be written as a sum of five squares of primes.  In his argument, which is based on the circle method, it would be possible to arrange for the primes to be distinct, and to guarantee many solutions.  In fact for five squares of primes (assuming the congruence condition $\pmod {24}$) there will be about $n^{3/2-\epsilon}$ representations of a large number $n$.  Note that representations where a prime is repeated, or representations with a given prime will be at most $O(n^{1+\epsilon})$ in number.  So one can guarantee many representations ($n^{1/2-\epsilon}$ at least) as a sum of five squares of distinct primes, and no primes shared among two such solutions. Once one has the result for five squares, of course every integer that is $j \pmod{24}$ for $j\ge 5$ may be expressed in many ways as a sum of $j$ squares of distinct primes.  That finishes the job.

This problem seems a little strange to me; I would appreciate some motivation of where it came from.

**Update**: Actually I can give a reference that will work.  It is work of Harman and Kumchev: see http://arxiv.org/pdf/0902.4190.pdf  .  Harman and Kumchev show that with very few exceptions, any number that is $3\pmod {24}$ and not a multiple of $5$ can be expressed as a sum of three squares of primes in $\gg n^{1/2-\epsilon}$ ways.  Note that one doesn't have to worry about Siegel zeros, as this is an almost all result.   From this and the argument above one can get that $12$ permutations suffice (writing $k=12 a +4b+3c$).

Comment: Be careful: we need not just distinct primes in each representation, but plenty of representations sharing no common primes. The first is not hard even without Hua's theorem, but I've never seen the second. Formally it is even impossible in the way you state it: if the number is even, every representation as a sum of squares of 5 primes should include 2...

Comment: I do not see the connection here. Could you put down your thoughts algebraically and symbolically as in the question?

Comment: @fedja Please note that Hua's theorem takes $n$ to be $5 \pmod {24}$ and that every prime square apart from $4$ and $9$ is $1 \pmod {24}$.  As for the number of representations, this is why I wrote that a reference would be hard to find, but the number of representations will be very many --- about $n^{3/2+o(1)}$ for five squares of distinct primes.

Comment: @JAS Here's an example if that helps of the proof.  Suppose $k=41=30+6+5$.  Then take the permutation $(1,2,...,30)(31,...,36)(37,...41)$ and its powers.  These give $30$ permutations of the primes $p_1$ to $p_{41}$.  If you add the vectors, the first thirty entries will match and they are the number $30N$ written as a sum of $30$ squares of distinct primes (assume all primes $\ge 5$ so the squares are $1\pmod{24}$).  Next six entries will be $5$ times a number that is a sum of six squares; and the last $5$ entries will be $6$ times a sum of $5$ squares.This is why we also want $5N$ and $6N$.

Comment: ah ic! good trick!

Comment: So you want 30N to be represented py p1 to p30, 5N by p31 to p36 and 6N by p37 to p41. Is this possible?

Comment: @JAS 6N by p_{31} to p_{36} and 5N by 37 to 41.  This is possible by choosing $N$ to be large and $1\pmod {24}$ and using Hua's theorem.  One also needs lots of ways of writing numbers as sums of five squares of primes.  This is standard from the circle method, but I don't know a reference.  See my comment to fedja also.

Comment: Why cant I do it in 25? k=25+5+5?

Comment: So another possible issue: $N = O(k^c)$ holds? It seems numbers N have to be very large. I see only that $t=30$ suffices for any $k$. It seems that if you fix $t=30$ for larger $k$, $N > 2^k$ may hold. Is there a way to relax $t$ while controlling $N$?

Comment: To JAS:  The solutions will be small.  You need essentially an integer having about $k$ solutions as a sum of thirty squares of primes.  This will be polynomial in $k$.  See my remarks on the number of solutions in Hua's theorem -- there are lots of ways of writing numbers as sums of squares of (sufficiently many) primes.

Comment: Interesting I did not expect the answer to have finite $t$.

Comment: @Lucia Hmm... Perhaps that's just the way you wrote your statement that confused me a bit. What you are saying is that we apply the circle method with plenty of primes removed before we do the counts (which is OK because it changes the trig. sums by a controllable amounts). Then it makes sense :-).